# Create interface from XML

Tags: xml, interface, alljoyn

Using the Introspection interface I obtain a String that represents an AllJoyn object in XML Introspection language. In the AllJoyn C++ API there is a function called *CreateInterfacesFromXml*. How to create an interface from this XML string in Java?

I think that the Code Generator is a tool that can not be used during execution.

Answer (score 1):

The java binding does not support the creation of alljoyn interfaces with a XML file.

Eventually you have to create a native C++ part and use CreateInterfacesFromXml method from there.